# Find the Outlook.Account object of a mailbox

Tags: email, outlook, vb6

**Accounts**

Let's say I have multiple accounts in Outlook ("bob@example.com" and "bob@gmail.com"):

[image]

**Mailboxes**

Each account can have multiple mailboxes. In this case the account bob@example.com has 3 mailboxes:

- "bob@example.com"
- "Example Support"
- "Online Archive - bob@example.com"

and the account bob@gmail.com only has 1 mailbox:

- "bob@gmail.com"

[image: [screenshot mailboxes]]

The screenshot is after [right clicking "Example Support" > Data File Properties... > Advanced]

**The mailbox "Example Support"**

This is the mailbox I'm interested in. It has the email address "support@example.com".

**Find Outlook.Store by it's email address**

I know how to find the Outlook.Store object for the mailbox "Example Support", given only it's email address:

```
Function GetStore(oApp As Outlook.Application, emailAddress As String) As Outlook.Store
    Dim oStore As Outlook.Store
    Set oStore = Nothing
    
    Dim s As Outlook.Store
    For Each s In oApp.Session.Stores
        If s.ExchangeStoreType = olExchangeMailbox Then
            Dim PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID As String
            PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661B0102"

            Dim ownerEntryId As String
            ownerEntryId = s.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString(s.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID))
            
            Dim oAddressEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
            Set oAddressEntry = oApp.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(ownerEntryId)
            
            Dim oExhangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
            Set oExhangeUser = oAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
            
            If oExhangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress = emailAddress Then
                Set oStore = s
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next s
    
    Set GetStore = oStore
End Function
```

**Question**

How do i find the Outlook.Account object of a mailbox, given only the email address of that mailbox?

**Details**

- I can see the Outlook.Account object with .SmtpAddress "bob@example.com" that i want, in the debugger. But, i can't find any relation between it and the mailbox for "Example Support", unlike in the screenshot.
- The Outlook.Store object for the mailbox "Example Support", is not the .DeliveryStore for the Outlook.Account object with .SmtpAddress "bob@example.com".

Comment: Is this a VB6 or VBA program?

Comment: @StayOnTarget it's a VB6 program. but i'm open to using .NET, and maybe C++. for now i've simply added an extra setting, for entering the Outlook.Account's SmtpAddress

Comment: @StayOnTarget it works the same in VBA, so why did you remove the VBA tag?

Comment: People tend to watch tags to see what questions they are interested in. So if the program is VB6 and not VBA, tagging it as such is more helpful, despite the languages being very similar.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you need to find `PR_SERVICE_UID` of the profile section where the store account properties are stored. Once you have that, you can look through all accounts ([IOlkAccountManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/iolkaccountmanager)) and check if you can find a matching [IOlkAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/iolkaccount) object with the same value of the `PROP_MAPI_SERVICE_UID` property. You can see these (and other) objects in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/).

You can do that in C++ or Delphi, but not in VBA or VB6 since it requires Extended MAPI.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes the [IRDOStore](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).`StoreAccount` property. You can also start with an [RDOAccount](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm) object (exposed in the [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Accounts` collection), cast it to [RDOExchangeAccount](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm#RDOExchangeAccount), and loop through the `IRDOExchangeAccount.AllStores` collection.

```
set oomStore = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Store
Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set redStore = Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(oomStore)
set redAccount = redStore.StoreAccount
Debug.Print "Store account name: " & redAccount.Name
Debug.Print "All account stores:"
for each otherStore in redAccount.AllStores
  Debug.Print otherStore.Name
next
```

Comment: do you know where i can find any documentation, listing more properties like PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID, PR_SERVICE_UID, PROP_MAPI_SERVICE_UID?

Comment: can what you are suggesting, be done in .NET?

Comment: Cannot be done in .Net alone since you'd need to use Extended MAPI, whcih requires native code, like C++ or Delphi. Redemption *can* be used from any language, C# / VB.Net and VBA included.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct correlation between accounts and stores except delivery stores. You even can add a new store to the profile at runtime, see [Add or remove a store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-add-or-remove-a-store) for more information.

The best what you could do is to try to retrieve a shared store by using the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. Getting the `Parent` property value can lead you to the store.